# Should this sentence take "on stage" or "onstage"?

Tags: word-usage

I'm not sure if I should use "onstage" or "on stage" here. Is this sentence okay as it is, or should I use "onstage" instead?

> It was decided that only actors should go on stage if that particular film won any awards at the awards show.

Since it is not used as an adjective here like "onstage antics," should I use "on stage" or "onstage"?

Comment: To me, I would use *on stage* because you don't have to describe a noun or modify a verb here but to give a location by a propositional phrase {on stage}. BTW *onstage* is an adjective and an adverb too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lean toward "on stage" here, because (in general) "onstage" refers to participating in some kind of performing art.

> Her role required her to be **onstage** the entire length of the play.

In this case the actors are just receiving an award.

> The two writers of the popular show were called back **on stage** to receive a special standing ovation.

However, I don't think anyone cares which you use, as there is very little difference between the two.  For example, this sounds just fine to me:

> Aside from some quick costume changes, Beyoncé was **on stage** every minute of the two-hour concert.